# double integration changing variables and finding boundaries

Tags: integration

This may be quite simple, but I am a little rusty and have had quite a few attempts at this and would appreciate some help.
The form of the integrand does not really matter, I am trying to change the measure of this double integration and also the corresponding boundaries.
The integration limits are

$$\int_{0}^{t}dt_{1}\int_{0}^{t}dt_{2} $$
So essentially I have a rectangle in the $(t_{1}-t_{2})$ plane. I would like to change the integration variable to 
$$\int_{y_{1_{int}}}^{y_{1_{fin}}}dy_{1}\int_{y_{2_{int}}}^{y_{2_{fin}}}dy_{2} $$
where 
$y_{1}=\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{2}$ and $y_{2}=t_{2}-t_{1}$. I think I need to split the integral into two parts but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first is getting our new volume element. For this we use the Jacobian, in this case that is
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{J} &=\frac{\partial(y_1,y_2)}{\partial(t_1,t_2)} \\
&=\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
y_{1t_1} & y_{1t_2} \\
y_{2t_1} & y_{2t_2}
\end{array}\right|=\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right| \\
&=1
\end{align}$$
So for us in this case the volume element stays the same which just makes things easier. Next is changing the bounds. Our region is the region enclosed by the lines
$$\begin{array}{cc}
t_1=0 & t_1=t \\
t_2=0 & t_2=t
\end{array}$$
We wish to get these boundaries in terms of $y_1$ and $y_2$, so to do that we solve for $t_1$ and $t_2$ in terms of $y_1$ and $y_2$.
$$\begin{align}
t_1=y_1-\frac{1}{2}y_2 \\
t_2=y_1+\frac{1}{2}y_2
\end{align}$$
Thus our new boundaries are
$$\begin{array}{cc}
y_1-\frac{1}{2}y_2=0 & y_1-\frac{1}{2}y_2=t \\
y_1+\frac{1}{2}y_2=0 & y_1+\frac{1}{2}y_2=t
\end{array}$$
Which gives us a parallelogram whose bottom vertex is the origin and whose height is $t$ and width is $2t$ ([demos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zttjgayc3c) of bounds for $t=4$). So from the looks of it we need to split up the integral to get
$$\begin{align}
I &=\int_{-t}^0dy_2\int_{-y_2/2}^{t+y_2/2}dy_1+\int_{0}^tdy_2\int_{y_2/2}^{t-y_2/2}dy_1 \\
&=\int_{-t}^tdy_2\left(\int_{-y_2/2}^{t+y_2/2}dy_1+\int_{y_2/2}^{t-y_2/2}dy_1\right)
\end{align}$$
Which I believe is the simplest way to put it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very clearly explained. You  really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly different way of doing things and thought I would share it with people.[this shows a change of basis essentially, hopefully the drawing is clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE4gy.jpg)